# GoJS Keep Group of Nodes copied via DraggingTool

Tags: javascript, gojs

Is there a way of copying Nodes with the `DraggingTool` including their `Part.containingGroup`? I know the `CommandHandler` has a property `copiesGroupKey`, but I can't find any similar functionality in the `DraggingTool`.

Maybe even better if there is a way to detect on which group the copied Nodes are being dropped to set the new `containingGroup`?
Is there an event to subscribe to when copied Nodes are being dropped?

I also noticed the same problem with the "Swim Lanes" sample here
http://gojs.net/latest/samples/swimLanes.html
Copying Nodes via the `CommandHandler` works fine, but if you "Control-Drag" them they are placed outside of any Group which should not be possible at all with that example I guess?!

Comment: I think I found something, in the `groupTemplate` the `mouseDrop: function(e, grp) {  if (!e.shift) return; ... }` will cancel the addition to the group. Is there a way to detect if the `grp.diagram.selection` is a copy or move operation, maybe check in the active tool

Comment: changing the `mouseDrop` condition to`if (e.diagram.currentTool.copiedParts === null && !e.shift) return;` seems to work. It's possible to copy the Nodes to the same or different Groups, but moving out of the Group only works when holding the shift key. I just leave this here as it might be a bug in the sample code as well

Answer (score 0):

You mean you are (CTRL) dragging the nodes within a group, you want to copy the group too? You would have to add the group to the collection being dragged. You could do this by overriding [DraggingTool.computeEffectiveCollection](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/DraggingTool.html#computeEffectiveCollection). Maybe something like:

```
  myDiagram.toolManager.draggingTool.computeEffectiveCollection = function (parts) {
    var map = go.DraggingTool.prototype.computeEffectiveCollection.call(this, parts);
    // add more stuff to map
    var it = parts.iterator;
    while (it.next()) {
      var p = it.value;
      if (p.containingGroup !== null) {
        var group = p.containingGroup;
        map.add(group, new go.DraggingInfo(group.location));
      }
    }
    return map;
  }
```

Comment: No, sorry if my explanation wasn't clear. I just want to set a group to the copied nodes when ctrl dragging them to another group (or the same for that matter). if you look at the official Swim Lane sample (link in my question) and try to ctrl drag a node the group is lost (it will be placed outside of the lanes!). I fixed it with the code mentioned in my comments for now.